# How to programmatically check the iPad version/model

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

Is there a method to check the version/model of an iPad (i.e iPad 1/2/3).
I am using some transparency in my iPad interfaces with multiple overlays. While working satisfactory on an iPad 2, an iPad 1 doesn't give as nice a user experience. So I would like to remove the transparency on iPad 1, but cannot find a way to know which iPad I am dealing with.

Is there a trick to distinguish between iPad 1 and higher versions which have a more powerful graphical processor (i.e. currently iPad 2 + 3)?

I read it is possible in the web browser, so there should be a way to get the model number in the code as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I check for the presence of a camera, which is not available on the iPad 1. Since the 2 and 3 have similar CPU capabilities, this has worked well for me (I'm in a similar situation, but with memory).

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    NSLog(@"iPad 2 or 3");
else
    NSLog(@"iPad 1");
```

Comment: This seems the simplest and will do the job!

Answer (score 15):

I hope that's what you need:

```
  NSString *platform = [self platform];

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"])    return @"iPhone 1G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"])    return @"iPhone 3G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"])    return @"iPhone 3GS";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"])    return @"iPhone 4";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,3"])    return @"Verizon iPhone 4";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"])    return @"iPhone 4S";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,1"])    return @"iPhone 5 (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,2"])    return @"iPhone 5 (GSM+CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,3"])    return @"iPhone 5c (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,4"])    return @"iPhone 5c (Global)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone6,1"])    return @"iPhone 5s (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone6,2"])    return @"iPhone 5s (Global)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,1"])    return @"iPhone 6+";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,2"])    return @"iPhone 6";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 1G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 2G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod3,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 3G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod4,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 4G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod5,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 5G";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"])      return @"iPad";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,1"])      return @"iPad 2 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,2"])      return @"iPad 2 (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,3"])      return @"iPad 2 (CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,4"])      return @"iPad 2 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,5"])      return @"iPad Mini (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,6"])      return @"iPad Mini (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,7"])      return @"iPad Mini (GSM+CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,1"])      return @"iPad 3 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,2"])      return @"iPad 3 (GSM+CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,3"])      return @"iPad 3 (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,4"])      return @"iPad 4 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,5"])      return @"iPad 4 (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,6"])      return @"iPad 4 (GSM+CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,1"])      return @"iPad Air (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,2"])      return @"iPad Air (Cellular)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,3"])      return @"iPad Air";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,4"])      return @"iPad Mini 2 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,5"])      return @"iPad Mini 2 (Cellular)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,6"])      return @"iPad Mini 2 (Rev)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,7"])      return @"iPad Mini 3 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,8"])      return @"iPad Mini 3 (A1600)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,9"])      return @"iPad Mini 3 (A1601)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad5,3"])      return @"iPad Air 2 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad5,4"])      return @"iPad Air 2 (Cellular)";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"i386"])         return @"Simulator";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"x86_64"])       return @"Simulator";
```

The code comes from: https://gist.github.com/1323251

Comment: I wouldn't really rely on this code for anything but debugging; it's pretty low-level and lacks explicit documentation. There are other ways to accomplish what the OP needs.

Comment: -1 #1: overkill compared to the OP's problem, #2 "It's for code like this that arrays were invented for!"

Comment: Will it be safe to guess that the new iPhone will be iPhone5,1

Answer (score 1):

Erica Sadun has utilities for this, written as categories on `UIDevice`. Available on her github repo [uidevice-extension](https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension).  UIDevice-Hardware.h/m specifically does what you want. Supports iPhone 5.