# Where do I find the suggested video bitrate for the iPad Pro?

Tags: ios, ipad, video, bitrate

I am looking for a suggested bitrate for video playback on the iPad Pro. In particular the 10"5 version. I am thinking of using 5MBit, but would like to find the reference for that.
Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's worth first distinguishing between bit rate and resolution - generally a device will have a certain 'native' resolution and sending anything which is much higher resolution may be wasteful and lower resolution may not look good.

The resolution is basically the number of pixels wide and high - for a given physical screen size higher resolution will mean more pixels per square cm, and (in theory) a better looking picture (in practice, there are many factors which affect how people perceive the quality of a picture - for example colour mapping and the increased roll out of HDR is seen by many as equally or more important).

The bit rate is simply how many bits per second are required to transport the video - you could take a silly example with a low resolution and a very inefficient codec, which would mean you use a lot of bandwidth to deliver a video which is much lower resolution than the device is capable of playing.

Having said all that, to go back to your question - different versions of the iPad have different capabilities so you need to check the version and dterenine the best format from that. Apple provide the specification information here:

- https://support.apple.com/specs/

See here for an answer which gives some more background:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/44010040/334402

Comment: Helped ! Thank you Mick!